# Connecting to Impala from R without Impala JDBC driver

Tags: r, ssl, putty, impala

For an undisclosed reason, my Impala does not have a JDBC driver installed. This is making the [connection from R to Impala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33551542/connect-r-and-impala) challenging.

I am able to connect (and query) to Impala shell via Putty. E.g.,

```
impala-shell --ssl -i some_name
```

Using the Putty connection mechanism/credentials, can this be performed from RStudio and bring in the `SELECT` results into a dataframe?

Comment: Maybe, if the result is not too large, you can export it to csv by using `impala-shell --ssl -i some_name -q "query" --output_file <output_filename> --output_delimiter=<character>` options?

Comment: Can this command be run from R without JDBC driver?

Comment: You can probably execute it via remote shell, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-a-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine. I'm no RStudio expert, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This worked in my Oracle BDA cluster.

```
library(dsreq)
print("Connecting to Impala...")
impaladb <- impalaConnection(pool='general')
dbResultsTempTbl <- dbGetQuery(impaladb, paste0("SELECT * FROM mytable") )

print("results")
print(dbResultsTempTbl)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ODBC driver to connect to impalaDB

```
library(ODBC)
drv <- odbc::odbc()
con <- DBI::dbConnect(drv = drv, driver = "Cloudera ODBC Driver for Impala",
    host = "your hostname", port = 21050, Schema = "your schema")
```